# The type or namespace name 'DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

Im recieving an error with the following piece of code in MVC3, any help on this would be appreciated:

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the namespace:

```
 using System.Data.Entity;
```

And also add a reference to `EntityFramework.dll`

Comment: It did work originally then I downloaded this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491 
since then it has stopped working

Comment: It did work originally then I downloaded this: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1491

Comment: how do you do that? sorry im new to this

Comment: If you have nuget installed right click References and choose manage nuget packages, then search for entityframework

Comment: Right clicked this and it does not appear, I presume I will need to install nuget?

Comment: The signature on the update version of 'NuGet Package Manager' does not match the signature on the installed version. Another error when trying to install nuget

Comment: unistall NuGet and reinstall it through the VS extention manager.

Comment: Download [this](http://packages.nuget.org/v1/package/download/entityframework/4.2.0.0) and add the reference to entity framework

Comment: downloaded the file but unable to open it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges, try to use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges:

```
Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Context>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this: `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourDbContext>());`